# I'm missing an Ajax parameter, but I'm passing it & the browser is confirming this

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

In a nutshell, I'm getting an error for not passing a parameter, but I am passing it. Below is what I've tried to do & the code.

My jQuery Ajax

```
var id = this.id;

    var viewd = JSON.stringify({
        'company': id,
        'seen':true,
        'viewCount':0,
        'email':false
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/WebServices/usageAjax.asmx/addView',
        data: viewd,
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

The code it's calling

```
[WebMethod]
public void addView(string company, bool seen, int viewCount, bool email)
{
        userManager um = new userManager();
        string user = um.id;
        um.addUsage(user, company, seen, 0, email);
}
```

Which returns this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: company.    at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection
> collection)    at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest
> request)    at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
> at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Despite chrome clearly stating a value is being passed:
[image]

Comment: You do not need to pass data as stringify method. Just pass your normally as formData.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29829468/34092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` to your Ajax Request:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/WebServices/usageAjax.asmx/addView',
    data: viewd,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' // <= Add this
});
```